# Parsing .DAT file with Python

Tags: python, parsing

I need to convert a `.dat` file that's in a specific format into a `.csv` file.

The `.dat` file has multiple rows with a repeating structure. The data is held in brackets and have tags.  Below is the sample data; it repeats throughout the data file:

> `{"name":"ABSDSDSRF","ID":"AFJDKGFGHF","lat":37,"lng":-122,"type":0,"HAC":5,"verticalAccuracy":4,"course":266.8359375,"area":"san_francisco"}`

Can anyone provide a starting point for the script?

Comment: That's JSON. You can parse it using the JSON module.

Comment: the problem it is in a .DAT file and I dont know how to bring it in as a JSON file. Can you provide a starting script?

Comment: If you open a .dat file in Sublime, does it show raw json?

Comment: In notepad it does. I am using wing though as my environment. :)

Comment: The file extension really doesn't matter for anything.

Comment: Is each data item on a separate line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will create a csv assuming each line in your .DAT is json. Just order the header list to your liking

```
import csv, json

header = ['ID', 'name', 'type', 'area', 'HAC', 'verticalAccuracy', 'course', 'lat', 'lng']

with open('file.DAT') as datfile:
    with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=header)
        writer.writeheader()
        for line in datfile:
            writer.writerow(json.loads(line))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your row is in json format. So, you can use:

```
import json
data = json.loads('{"name":"ABSDSDSRF","ID":"AFJDKGFGHF","lat":37,"lng":-122,"type":0,"HAC":5,"verticalAccuracy":4,"course":266.8359375,"area":"san_francisco"}')

print data.get('name')
print data.get('ID')
```

This is only a start point. You have to iter all the .dat file. At the end, you have to write an exporter to save the data into the **csv** file.

Comment: so I have a .dat file that contains the information. I get a ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 45670 column 77 (char 216 - 11091968) when putting into python.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex to find all of the data items.  Use `ast.literal_eval` to convert each data item into a dictionary.  Collect the items in a list.

```
import re, ast
result = []
s = '''{"name":"ABSDSDSRF","ID":"AFJDKGFGHF","lat":37,"lng":-122,"type":0,"HAC":5,"verticalAccuracy":4,"course":266.8359375,"area":"san_francisco"}'''

item = re.compile(r'{[^}]*?}')
for match in item.finditer(s):
    d = ast.literal_eval(match.group())
    result.append(d)
```

---

If each data item is on a separate line in the file You don't need the regex - you can just iterate over the file.

```
with open('file.dat') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        line = ast.literal_eval(line)
        result.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use json.load:

```
import json
with open (filename) as fh:
  data = json.load (fh)
   ...
```

Comment: I get this error: ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 45670 column 77 (char 216 - 11091968)